# Laravel where condition on date column haves a date range string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a column name(available_on) which haves a value in string ('11/10/2020 - 11/14/2020') and now i want to apply condition where current date exists in between this string i.e between 11/10/2020 And 11/14/2020

And I want to do this in mysql query.

You can give also a solution in laravel or php

Comment: See normalisation.

Answer (score 1):

```
// if available_on is from a object named $data so :
$availableOn = explode(" - ", $data->available_on); // split two date
$dateFrom = strtotime($availableOn[0]); // convert into unix_timestamp
$dateTo = strtotime($availableOn[1]);

if( time() > $dateFrom  AND time() < $dateTo ){ // check if current time() between two
   return true; // it's in available time
}else{
   return false; // it's not in this time
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine with this code but i want to do this in mysql query can u plz guide

Comment: And also can u give solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64728979/angular-js-ng-model-value-is-null-in-bootstrap-datepicker